# Bind life cycle of a object to its source

Tags: c++, oop

I currently have code like this:

```
static void foo(function<void(B)> func)
{
    A a;
    B* b = a->getB_ptr();
    func(*b);
}
```

`foo(func)` is meant to be an interface to easily consume b, and to hide its source at the same time. But the lifetime of b is bound to the existance of a. I want to get rid of that functional style and use a OO pattern instead. I already thought about subclassing B from A, but I cannot touch their implementations.

Comment: @Gluttton Well, it could provide -> operator

Comment: What do you do in `getB_ptr()`? If you create a new instance, it will life after deletion of a

Comment: So long as func doesn't keep a reference to `a` or anything it manages after it exits, the code is fine.

Comment: "But the lifetime of b is bound to the existance of a" is that a problem or a requirement?

Comment: @user3755692 A is legacy code, I think b is a new instance, but b only works alright if a is still around.

Comment: @user3125280 Its a requirement since I cannot touch A or B and change that.

Comment: that's interesting - i guess the next question is where a comes from. is it unique/singleton? is it being generated by some factory like interface? do you need a new A every-time you want a new B or can you reuse an A? you could create a functor class which looks like func when called, but automagically creates a B, passes it, and gets rid of it. personally, i don't mind it the way it is,what exactly is it lacking in your opinion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?:

```
class C {
  A a
  public:
  B& operator ->() { return *a->getB_ptr(); }
}
```